# Java loop took only one of my records and don't even look at other

Tags: java, loops

I created loop, which is checking if discSum > minSum. But for some reason println in console giving me always same numbers and system setting (setComp) for all records. It seems, that loop just took one of my record and not even looking at others. In this case, I need that loop will took only one record, one time and use function (setComp) only for this one records. What is wrong here?

My data after loop:

```
"Type": "A",
"DiscSum": 0.11925,
"minSum": 0.15,
"Comp": 0.20.


"Type": "A",
"DiscSum": 0.22270,
"minSum": 0.15,
"Comp": 0.20.


"Type": "A",
"DiscSum": 0.016,
"minSum": 0.15,
"Comp": 0.20.
```

Prinln in console shows:

```
0.15
0.22270


0.15
0.22270


0.15
0.22270


0.15
0.22270


0.15
0.22270


0.15
0.22270
```

Code:

```
   for (int Index = 0; Index < Tariff.size(); Index++) { 
    if(Tariff.get(Index).getType().equals("A") && minSum != null && Tariff.get(Index).getDiscSum().compareTo(minSum) == 1){
        System.out.println(minSum);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(Tariff.get(Index).getDiscSum());
        Tariff.get(Index).setComp(Tariff.get(Index).getPrice().subtract((Tariff.get(Index).getPrice().subtract(minSum)).min(maxSum)));
        break;
 }
}
```

Comment: At a glance: you can't just check if the result of `compare == 1`, you must check if it is `> 0`.  `compare` is allowed to return 1, 10, 1234, 100000, or any other positive number.

Answer (score 0):

You have a break statement inside the if condition. Once the loop falls into if condition and break statement will hit. It will terminate the loop also.

Add a few `System.out.println()` to get the idea of what's going on.

```
for (int Index = 0; Index < Tariff.size(); Index++) { 
    System.out.println(Index);
    if(Tariff.get(Index).getType().equals("A") && minSum != null && Tariff.get(Index).getDiscSum().compareTo(minSum) == 1){
        System.out.println(minSum);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(Tariff.get(Index).getDiscSum());
        Tariff.get(Index).setComp(Tariff.get(Index).getPrice().subtract((Tariff.get(Index).getPrice().subtract(minSum)).min(maxSum)));
        System.out.println("Breaking the loop");
        break;
   }
}

System.out.println("Exit");
```